# Jquery stop animation on mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery

A bit of JQuery taken from http://briancray.com/2009/05/06/twitter-style-alert-jquery-cs-php/ which should give a nice old-twitter style notification.

How do I edit the code below to stop the div hiding on a mouseover?

**UPDATE: I still want the div to slideup after the mouseover has finished.**

```
$(function () {
    var $alert = $('#alert');
    if($alert.length) {
        var alerttimer = window.setTimeout(function () {
            $alert.trigger('click');
        }, 5000);       
        $alert.animate({height: $alert.css('line-height') || '50px'}, 200).click(function () {
            window.clearTimeout(alerttimer);
            $alert.animate({height: '0'}, 200);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Am I right in assuming you've tried a `.stop()` on elements in a mouseover event?

Comment: assume nothing, I've tried a few things but not stop

Comment: Well `.stop()` stops all animations on a given element, so even if it was half way through a hiding animation (btw why arn't you using `slideUp()`?) it would just stop dead. Is that what you want?

Comment: Rather reset the 5 second timer rather than freeze everything in place forever.

Comment: See my answer, I think it's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly (which I'm probably not), you want something like this:

```
var alerttimer, alertBox = $('#alert');
function resetTimeout() {
        if (alerttimer) {
                clearTimeout(alerttimer);
        }
        alerttimer = setTimeout(function() {
                alertBox.trigger('click');
        }, 5000);
}
$(function () {
        if(alertBox.length) {
                resetTimeout();
                alertBox.animate({ height: alertBox.css('line-height') || '50px' }, 200).click(function () {
                        window.clearTimeout(alerttimer);
                        alertBox.animate({ height: '0px' }, 200);
                }).mouseover(function () {
                        clearTimeout(alerttimer);
                }).mouseout(function () {
                        resetTimeout();
                });
        }
});
```

It's important to note that the above is very much untested.

Comment: Sorry, do you get an error? It could be something really obvious, pretty tired right now.

Comment: No error just does not prevent the animation up if you hover over it

Comment: Well it's not going to, it's just going to reset the timer to be another 5 seconds later after you mouseover. I think I fully get what you want now, whilst you're mouseovering it shouldn't hide, then when you mouse out again it should reset the timeout to be 5 seconds? Just updated my answer, see if that works!

Comment: bingo! Thanks for the patience!